# VueJS MDB-datatable doesn't render data from the API call

Tags: vue.js, mdbootstrap

I'm using vueJs MDB-datatable to display my data coming from my API.
I followed the MDB-datable documentation in handling the "OtherJSON structure" but it didn't re-render the data from the API request.

I tried different callback beforeCreate, created, beforeMount, and mounted, the data was changed but still, it didn't render the latest data.

Here's the code:

```html
<template>
  <mdb-datatable
    :data="tableData"
    striped
    bordered
  />
</template>

<script>
import 'mdbvue/build/css/mdb.css';
import { mdbDatatable } from 'mdbvue';

export default {
  components: {
    mdbDatatable
  },
  data: () => ({
    tableData: {
      columns: [],
      rows: []
    }
  }),
  created() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        let keys = ["id", "name", "username"];
        let entries = this.filterData(json, keys);

        //columns
        this.tableData.columns = keys.map(key => {
          return {
            label: key.toUpperCase(),
            field: key,
            sort: 'asc'
          };
        });

        console.log(this.tableData.columns);
        //rows
        entries.map(entry => this.tableData.rows.push(entry));
        console.log(this.tableData.rows);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  methods: {
    filterData(dataArr, keys) {
      let data = dataArr.map(entry => {
        let filteredEntry = {};
        keys.forEach(key => {
          if(key in entry) {
            filteredEntry[key] = entry[key];
          }
        })
        return filteredEntry;
      })
      return data;
    }
}
</script>
```

The MDB-datatable documentation seems to be straight forward but I don't know which part I'm missing.

I'm new to VueJS. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current version of MDB Vue (5.5.0) takes a reference to the `rows` and `columns` arrays and reacts when these arrays mutate rather than reacting to changes to the property bound to the `data` prop itself.

I see you are already mutating rather than replacing the `rows` array, so you need to do the same with the `columns` array.

```
    //columns
    this.tableData.columns.push(...keys.map(key => {
      return {
        label: key.toUpperCase(),
        field: key,
        sort: 'asc'
      };
    }));
```